# Store the function returned value in a database

Tags: javascript, sql-server, client-side

I am trying to send the value returned by a function to a database using client-server model. I am using Javascript as my client model. How can I connect to a server to send my data to the database.

For example; from the below code, I want to store abc in the database.

```
<blink>
<html>
<head><script>

var t = "abc";
function test(){
return t;}      // RETURNED VALUE WILL BE "abc"

</script></head>

<body onload = "test()">
</body></html>
</blink>
```

Comment: What are your options for the server side? Javascript? PHP? Java?

Comment: You should take a look at AJAX then. It allows loading content asynchronously. Are you using raw Javascript or are you working with a framework like jquery?

Comment: I'm using raw javascript. But my main concern is how do I connect the html file with the javasscript code to the ajax script?

Comment: By using AJAX... I suggest you google it and read up on it.

Comment: Could you, if possible provide me with some links...cause I wasn't able to find any appropriate ones

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interface with a database server directly with Javascript. You would need to use some sort of server side script like ASP.NET, PHP, Java, etc.

Comment: I want to use a PHP script but how do I connect it with my html file which contains the javascript code?

Comment: You should look at a PHP tutorial such as this one http://w3schools.com/php/default.asp You can "connect" the php with the html in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Reply in answer of your comment concerning AJAX I suggest you have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX